# Can not set a value in a text input

Tags: c#, watin

I have a frame in my page. I am trying to change the input field with the following:

```
Frame.TextField(Find.ById("blah")).Value ="test";
```

This sets the value but when I submit my form nothing happens as there is some validation on the input when entering the information.

If I have the following

```
Frame.TextField(Find.ById("blah")).TypeText("test");
```

The input is highlighted by no text goes in the box. I get a timeout. What could be going wrong?

Comment: I don't know c# but I expect that .value can only be used to fetch the value, but not to set it. Look for a setter method like .setText() or such.

Answer (score 0):

John - continue using your code

```
Frame.TextField(Find.ById("blah")).Value ="test";
```

but maybe then click on some other field so the browser will validate the value. On other note - what error do you get? Can you give us a code snipset

Comment: No joy sadly. Getting a time out error when using Frame.TextField(Find.ById("blah")).TypeText("test");

Comment: So WatiN can't find an element with id = "blah". I'm not sure about the usage of Frame.TextField - it should be something like ie.Frame(Find.ById("frameId")).TextField(Find.ById("blah")).Value ="test"; A html code would be useful :)

Comment: It finds it. I can set the value on it. I can get the TypeText to turn the box yellow. It just is not firing off validation. I think this is more to do with having a very old frame based app rather than WatiN.